# Azure DevOps on-premise costs

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Seems strange asking this on SO but that's what MS want us to do so here goes...

I'm looking at setting up an on-premise Azure DevOps 2019 server, but as usual the licensing and costs aren't very transparent.

Our dev team are likely to be getting Visual Studio Pro subscriptions, which I believe comes with a DevOps server license and CALs. What happens if we stop these subscriptions - does it mean we can no longer use our on-premise DevOps server?

I'm not very clear on what "extras" we may need to pay for (extensions, pipelines), and I don't want to be hit by any surprises. The essential requirements are:

- Be able to trigger a build on check-in. I can't tell if this is a built-in feature or requires some kind of extension and/or pipeline (and if so free or not?)
- Use build tasks to create NuGet packages and host these on the in-house server. Again, does this require any paid extensions or pipelines?
- There should be no limits on monthly build time (unlike VSTS which I believe is 240 minutes)

Answer (score 7):

To my best understanding:

You can run Azure DevOps Server 2019 with [at least one Visual Studio Professional or Enterprise license](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/pricing-details/).

The features available to each user are based on the licence assigned to the user: Stakeholders (no license) get the very basics, Basic access (Professional) gives you most of the features, Enterprise gives you all the features.

The most notable differences between Basic and Enterprise are:

- View Releases and Manage Approvals
- Artifacts Microsoft published
- Azure DevOps Extensions

However, per [this annoucement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2019?view=azure-devops#changes-to-artifacts-and-release-management-deployment-pipeline-licensing), Artifacts are now included in the Basic/professional license.

So with only professional licenses you should be good for triggering builds, publishing and using nuget-packages via Artifact feeds. I'd think that installing extensions might require Enterprise user and haven't tested "View Releases and Manage Approvals" without Enterprise license yet. That seems to have changed from older TFS we've been using, in which Basic users were able to create and view releases.

So would recommend getting at least one Enterprise license, in any case.

Answer (score 1):

one and two are free, third one is free with self hosted agent and 1800 minutes with hosted agent, if you are an opensource project you have lots of free compute time (dont think this applies to Azure Devops server though).

Build and release pipelines are included in Azure Devops Server 2019. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2019?view=azure-devops#changes-to-artifacts-and-release-management-deployment-pipeline-licensing

Comment: Why would you want a hosted agent when using your own on-premise server - won't it always be self-hosted? Also, I've seen an "artifact" extension mentioned, but not sure what it's for. Would I need this for #2?

Comment: no, you only need those if you want to store package in a hosted feed

Comment: So what is the difference between a feed and a repo? I'm guessing I just need a repo - somewhere to store the built packages, and from where they will be restored when building projects that reference them. (We do this already with TFS, but it's a manual process to create the package then copy it to a UNC share. This is configured as a "package source" in VS settings/NuGet.targets file).

Comment: Artifacts and release pipelines are included in the Azure DevOps Server 2019. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2019?view=azure-devops#changes-to-artifacts-and-release-management-deployment-pipeline-licensing