# TFS 2018 not recognizing SQL Server 2019

Tags: tfs-2018

I have installed TFS 2018 Update 3.2 in Windows Server 2019 machine.
I have NOT used Express edition of TFS 2018.

The Database server version is Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Standard.
I am migrating from TFS 2013 to TFS 2018 (Update 3.2).
I restored the Tfs_Configuration database to new SQL Database server.

The Application Tier and Data Tier are in different servers.

When i configure TFS 2018 i am able to connect to the SQL Server 2019.

But during readiness check i get a error message which says 'SQL Server 2017' is being used.

TF255146: The SQL Server instance you specified (PH-DB00004) is version 'SQL Server 2017', which is not supported by this version of Team Foundation Server. For more information about supported versions of SQL Server, visit https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/setup-admin/requirements

Has anyone else encountered such issues during TFS 2018 configuration.

The SQL requirements for TFS 2018 shows SQL Server 2016 (SP1) onwards.

Kindly suggest how to proceed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're mis-reading the documentation.

The documentation doesn't say that SQL Server 2016 SP1 and "onwards" is supported. It lists several specific supported versions, none of which are SQL Server 2019. Your question even includes a link that explicitly spells it out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/requirements?view=azure-devops-2020#azure-sql-database-and-sql-server

- TFS 2018

  - SQL Server 2017
  - SQL Server 2016 (minimum SP1)

Those are the supported versions. Just those versions.

Comment: Thank you. Yes i misread the documentation. So then I need to migrate to Azure DevOps 2020. I went through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55652494/azure-devops-on-premise-costs  which says there is no cost if we have visual studio enterprise or professional license. Can you please suggest if my understanding is right. If we have visual studio enterprise or professional license and SQL Server 2019 standard edition then there wont be any additional cost if we use Azure DevOps 2020 provided number of developers using Azure DevOps 2020 is less than 5