# Azure DevOps Server/Services licensing question

Tags: azure-devops

Apologies if this is the wrong location for this.  We are currently on TFS 2015 and considering a move to either Azure DevOps Services or on-premize Azure DevOps Server 2020.

For DevOps Services, we already have an Azure subscription.    Is there an additional charge on top of our existing subscription to use Services?

For DevOps Server, we just purchase a new software license from Microsoft?

"With Azure DevOps Server 2019 you can either pay month-to-month through Azure or you can buy classic software licenses which requires a 3-year commitment. Buying through Azure provides bonus of entitling you to use our cloud service, so you can move to the cloud at your own pace."

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Azure DevOps Server 2020, you should first check if you have Visual Studio subscriptions (professional or enterprise) that include the server license. You most likely do, so no need for additional server licenses from Microsoft. Then decide if users that don't currently have the mentioned licenses need either one of those or a basic license, or if they a good to go with just a limited stakeholder access.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/server/

[Azure DevOps on-premise costs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55652494/azure-devops-on-premise-costs/55690344#55690344)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/get-started-stakeholder?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process

For Azure DevOps Services, the answer is a bit more complicated. The basic plan is free for 5 team members, and some CI/CD and artifact storage capabilities. Additional CI/CD and storage capabilities, and extra users add costs per month.  Test Plans also cost extra. You can calculate costs here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/

Existing Visual Studio Subscribers can use Azure DevOps with that license, and also bring an extra self-hosted job with them:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/subscriptions/vs-azure-devops

If this sounds confusing, that's probably because it is and I've probably also missed out something here.